# Store GAE App settings between requests: use webapp2 registry?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2, app-engine-ndb

I use Google App Engine with the webapp2 framework (Python).

Almost every request to my app needs to consider a few settings that are rarely changed. My current implementation has a class

```
class Settings(ndb.Model):
    # a few ndb.KeyProperty and ndb.BooleanProperty types
```

and each requesthandler uses a function

```
def get_settings():
    s = Settings.get_by_id('settings')
    if not s:
        s = Settings(id='settings')
        s.put()
    return s
```

to retrieve the single entity with ID 'settings'. NDB automatically stores this entity in memcache, so the function is quite fast, but today I discovered webapp2's [registry](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/app.html#registry) attribute.

1. Is it a good idea to have `get_settings` write the settings entity in the registry and try to retrieve it from there, using NDB/memcache only as a fallback?
2. Is that what the registry is for? The documentation only has an example for a lazy import.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a quick look at the source code:
http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/_modules/webapp2.html#WSGIApplication

The registry is a dictionary, local to the WSGIApplication object.  You'll get a separate WSGIApplication object on each GAE instance that's running.  So if subsequent HTTP requests hit different instances, they'll get different WSGIApplication objects, and hence different registries.  It's also not shared across multiple instances in memcache.

The registry pretty replaces global variables.  Using global variables is a bit dangerous in App Engine, since values are not shared between instances.  A common use is to cache data or objects that take time to initialize.  For example, if you use a lot of regular expressions, you can compile them the first time you use them, and keep them stored in the registry, so you don't need to recompile them on a later request.

In terms of storing settings, it's probably a bad idea.  It could be done, provided you are ok with resetting each instance (and hence the registry with that instance) whenever you change the settings.

Comment: Great answer, thank you @dragonx. Any comments on my current implementation?

Comment: I think your current ndb implementation is fine, if you imagine you need to change the settings on the fly.  It will increase your costs since you can potentially read from the db a lot if your memcache gets flushed.  I personally have been just hardcoding my settings and uploading new versions when I needed to change the version, and that's worked fine for me (really depends on your use case).

Comment: Thanks. I have a non-technical admin who needs to be able to change the settings, so hard-coding them is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

1. I have been using registry in a while now and can’t recall any problems I’ve faced. So yeah you can use it if you want to.

Depending on the data you wanna keep track of, you might also opt to use the webapp2 [Sessions](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/sessions.html) library. One advantage of using sessions is that you can write and read from cookies so you would be saving some writes and reads in the memcache (which Google charges you for).

2. I’m not sure what the developers had in mind when they wrote it, I guess there is no way to find out now.